# Create dom elem on the fly or hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Which is better performance-wise in a slideshow app,

A) store data in an array and create dom elements (divs with images and text mostly) when slide is to appear, remove when is to disappear

Or

B) create all divs upon page load (already from serverside) and move them around z-index wise (using display/visibility property)?

Factors maybe affecting the choice:

1) slides could be 5 or 50, is either method preferrable for small/big slideshows?

2) transition effects will be used when switching between slides, will it be more resource consuming to use for instance a fade if there are 45 other slides hidden (display/visibility css) or stacked z-index wise underneath the current slide, or does it not matter for the browser rendering how many other objects the page has?

------- UPDATE ---------

Another related question (and since I already got one "close" vote on this I don't dare start another thread like this one, better to just go on here):

I have multiple slideshows up on the same page. Currently I solve it by IFRAMEs (I know, nobody likes them anymore, but they do the trick for me).

Now, I'm curious as for browser/client resources, is it much more greedy to have two IFRAMEs with separate documents and script processes running simultaneously, or is it more greedy to keep both slideshows in one DOM and run both slideshowscript-threads there?

Comment: Why did you decide to go for iframes? That has to be less efficient as you're creating a whole new document each time. I don't see what you gain from that at all. Javascript has a shared namespace in any case so you'd need to be careful variable names didn't collide etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to load in all elements on the initial DOM load. You'll use a lot of resources "painting" as google dev tools calls it as you move z-indexes of "visible to browser" images will not perform very good at all. The browser still has to "paint" each image. Use **hide()** and **show()**. Basically sets **display:none;**. The browser does not have to paint hidden elements in the DOM.

EDIT: Question update: The answer below answers your iFrame question, but doesn't address your question about hogging resources. I don't know how chrome handles iFrames, but if all your script is on one page, it's left up to the browser to process the data using system-side resources. Chrome's V8 engine is amazing at multithreading js processes. I'd say with two pages, not only would double-function work add resources, chrome might not be able to multithread multiple scripts in iFrames. Not sure, but its a possibility.

EDIT: Question update: iFrames? Terrible. It's not good to have two scripts running asynchronously when you can make your JS dynamic. For example.

First Page's code:

```
var imgArray = [];
function fetchImageArray() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"thispagesimages.php"
        success: function(data) {
            imgArray = data.imgs;
        }
    });
}
```

Second Page:

```
var imgArray = [];
function fetchImageArray() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"thatpagesimages.php"
        success: function(data) {
            imgArray = data.imgs;
        }
    });
}
```

**OR a dynamic function - no iFrames.**
Single page fetch function

```
function fetchImageArray(urlg, ss) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlg
        data: {whichSlideShow: ss}
        success: function(data) {
            return data.imgs;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So performance-wise it's better to set display to none (or hide/show methods) for all slides except current and maybe next, because then the browser won't have to worry about them while rendering, or "painting"?

Comment: @MattiasSvensson Correct. The best way to see this is use Chrome Dev Tools to view frames under timeline. Storing in arrays will cache alot of objects and cause problems under profiles>heap snapshots in dev tools. In any case, display:none (the method that hide() uses) causes the object to be "removed" from the DOM (same as hidden to browsers - does not keep the object in memory - only caches the props), which is a lot more efficient, IMO. It will still cache the css data, but you won't have arrays of data in your code AND css.

Comment: I can't find any reference to your assertion that display:none frees resources.  The image is certainly still present in the browser cache. Display:none doesn't remove the object from the DOM, it just hides it..

Comment: It "removes" it from the rendering engine. When an image is below another, the browser still has to render it. It's still "present" in the DOM. If you don't believe me, grab some huge images, set background-attachment:fixed. and apply the z-index method and the hide/show method. Watch the performance on scrolling. Frame view on timeline rocks for this.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't draw it so CPU load is reduced.. but the resources aren't released. If you have 50 images that are hidden, they're still taking up memory and the elements still exist. If you're concerned solely with performance then yes agreed

Comment: @WindsorAndy OP: "Which is better performance-wise in a slideshow app,"

Comment: @oswebdesign yes I get that. I was questioning your statement that display:none causes the object to be removed from the DOM (it doesn't) and removed from memory (it doesn't).

Comment: @WindsorAndy When you say memory (I've done it, too) I think you mean cache or a HDD-based memory. When you use display:none, it removes the Object from the rendering "memory" which is all that matters about performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have images and text I would preload the images and store the text for each slide in an array.  It depends upon the transition effect you want between slides as to how I'd set them up in the DOM.

If you're preloading a lot you've the option of keeping a holding image on-show until they're all loaded or setting some sort of flag so the next image is picked from the pool of currently-loaded images if you want action as quickly as possible,

Simple image preloader:

```
twdc.preloadimage = function(imagepath) {
var oImg = new Image();     
oImg.onload = function(){}
oImg.src = imagepath;
}
```

You could use the onload function to push the imagepath into an array of fully-loaded images and have the roller cycle through that.

If I were fading one out and the next in, I'd only have two slide elements - load up the next slide in the DIV (or whatever) with the lower Z-index then fade out the current slide, revealing the next. Then I'd copy the contents of the background slide to the foreground (the user won't notice this) and set it's opacity to 100. Then you can repeat the process.

Otherwise you're mucking about with multiple z-indices which if you have 50.. this also simply scales to any number of images.

I can't be sure about the speed aspect but my guess is it wouldn't be noticeable unless the machine is very low-powered.

If you're sliding the elements in, a UL / LI layout would work. Set the UL to position:absolute and adjust the style.left to reveal the next.  Again, you could have an LI for each image or just have 2 and do as above - eg if your images are 100px wide, set the UL to 200px with a masking DIV containing it of 100px width.
[image: illustration of side-sliding roller layout]
Load up image 2 in LI no.2 then transition the UL left from offset 0 to -100px revealing #2.  Then load this same image 2 into LI no.1 and set the style.left of the UL back to 0 - repeat the process..

Comment: When you say preload, do you mean to insert the image in a div? How would you keep track of what images are loaded, is there a method to check that?

Comment: No, load the image into the browser cache - I've added some code to my answer to do this. The onload function is empty here but you could use that to build an array of loaded images and use that as the list of source files for the roller.Or, if you want to wait until all have loaded, increment a counter on each onload event and hold off animating the roller until that reaches the number of images you're loading

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep your data in an array, and keep a cache of generated pages, which will include the currently visible page and neighboring pages. This way, the transition the pages will be smooth as they are already loaded when the user navigates to them.

When the user switch page, remove the farthest page from the cache and generate the next page in the direction the user navigated. You can do this during jQuery animation functions (such as `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`, `slideUp()`, etc).

Comment: by "remove from the cache" do you mean display:none or jQuery remove() that slide?

Comment: I mean `.remove()`. I suppose `display:none` or `hide()` also works but it does not delete the page from the DOM, which is what I intend to do.

Comment: ok. Are you and oswebdesign about 180 degrees opposite on this issue then, or did I misunderstand one of you?

Comment: After some Google searches, I think both methods will work. I can't tell which one surpasses the other performance-wise, but I would expect the user to not notice a difference however you implement it.

Comment: @nevercode Really, you won't notice a performance difference between the two. The only performance issue that arises is with rendering engines trying to render images. .hide() will cache css props. I have not tested that with .remove(). It would be best to cache the css props and make each image a div w/ background image. That way if he .show()'s the image after showing it once before, it won't have to reload the same image, only render the data it has in memory. Seems theoretically correct according to API documentation.